# add new key/value pairs to each object in JSON array in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm playing around with the USDA nutrition dataset and have converted it from CSV to JSON. I want to insert new key/value pairs to each object in the array and add the data later. Anyone know how to do that in Sublime Text?

My data currently looks like this:

`{ "name": "Butter, salted", "group": "Dairy and Egg Products", "protein ": 0.85, "calcium ": 0.024, "sodium ": 0.714, "fiber ": 0, "vitamin C": 0, "potassium ": 0.024, "carbohydrate ": 0.06, "sugars ": 0.06, "fat ": 81.11, "water ": 15.87, "calories": 717, "saturated fat": 51.368, "monounsaturated fat": 21.021, "polyunsaturated fat ": 3.043, "id": 27485 },`

And I want to add two new keys (description and category) with empty values, so each object would then look like this:

`{ "name": "Butter, salted", "group": "Dairy and Egg Products", "protein ": 0.85, "calcium ": 0.024, "sodium ": 0.714, "fiber ": 0, "vitamin C": 0, "potassium ": 0.024, "carbohydrate ": 0.06, "sugars ": 0.06, "fat ": 81.11, "water ": 15.87, "calories": 717, "saturated fat": 51.368, "monounsaturated fat": 21.021, "polyunsaturated fat ": 3.043, "id": 27485, "description": "", "storage": "" },`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the sort of thing I usually do directly in Sublime; depending on what's needed, I usually use a tool like [jsonformatter.org](https://jsonformatter.org/json-editor) (for simple modifications) or for more complex alterations I usually end up writing a simple script in Python.